# Pandas - Using `.rolling()` on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

Consider a pandas `DataFrame` which looks like the one below

```
      A     B     C
0  0.63  1.12  1.73
1  2.20 -2.16 -0.13
2  0.97 -0.68  1.09
3 -0.78 -1.22  0.96
4 -0.06 -0.02  2.18
```

I would like to use the function `.rolling()` to perform the following calculation for `t = 0,1,2`:

- Select the rows from `t` to `t+2`
- Take the 9 values contained in those 3 rows, from all the columns. Call this set `S`
- Compute the 75th percentile of `S` (or other summary statistics about `S`)

For instance, for `t = 1` we have 
  S = { 2.2 , -2.16, -0.13,  0.97, -0.68,  1.09, -0.78, -1.22,  0.96 } and the 75th percentile is 0.97.

I couldn't find a way to make it work with `.rolling()`, since it apparently takes each column separately. I'm now relying on a for loop, but it is really slow.

Do you have any suggestion for a more efficient approach?

Comment: what about [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Comment: You have enough rep know that *not post the data as picture*

Comment: @RushabhMehta: that's exactly the function I am trying to use, but I don't understand how pull the data from the 3 columns A,B and C together to compute the percentile.

Comment: Just paste it as text and format it as code.  Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I don't like the answers involving reshaping things. I used  [`scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter.html) to do this properly, though it needed some trial and error to get the same effect as Pandas' `rolling`'s `center=False` effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to `stack` the data and then multiply your window size by the number of columns and slice the result by the number of columns. Also, since you want a forward looking window, reverse the order of the stacked `DataFrame`

```
wsize = 3
cols = len(df.columns)

df.stack(dropna=False)[::-1].rolling(window=wsize*cols).quantile(0.75)[cols-1::cols].reset_index(-1, drop=True).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
0    1.12
1    0.97
2    0.97
3     NaN
4     NaN
dtype: float64
```

In the case of many columns and a small window:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

wsize = 3
df2 = pd.concat([df.shift(-x) for x in range(wsize)], 1)
s_quant = df2.quantile(0.75, 1)

# Only necessary if you need to enforce sufficient data. 
s_quant[df2.isnull().any(1)] = np.NaN
```

Output: `s_quant`

```
0    1.12
1    0.97
2    0.97
3     NaN
4     NaN
Name: 0.75, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is not equivalent, as it would compute the statistics many more times. This is because the window would move every 1 entry and not every 3. In my real dataset I have many more columns than 3, so this actually makes a huge difference computationally speaking.

Comment: @Abramodj I find it takes 8x longer for 1000x the number of columns. So as long as you have a reasonable number of columns, the excess probably wont kill you. It wasn't clear that you needed an extremely performant solution over just a solution to your problem. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Actually, I have more than 10k columns

Comment: About one thousand, so the for loop is actually feasible in this case. I just wanted to understand if this can be done, as it could be very useful in other circumstances.

Comment: @ALollz I think you should specify dropna=True in stack, otherwise the window size would be consistent

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo...definitely: stack(dropna=False)

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy ravel. Still you may have to use for loops.

```
for i in range(0,3):
    print(df.iloc[i:i+3].values.ravel())
```

If your `t` steps in 3s, you can use numpy `reshape` function to create a `n*9` dataframe.

Comment: This is the solution I am using at the moment, which requires a for loop. It is not as fast as `rolling` because it is not vectorized

Comment: @Abramodj Have you tried this: `x = pd.concat([df, df.shift(-1),df.shift(-2)], axis=1)` then `x['m'] = x.mean(axis=1)`. For quartile you can use `x['q3'] = x.quantile(0.75, axis=1)`.