# Rolling average all values of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame and I want to calculate on a rolling basis the average of all the value: for all the columns, for all the observations in the rolling window.

I have a solution with loops but feels very inefficient. Note that I can have `NaNs` in my data, so calculating the sum and dividing by the shape of the window would not be safe (as I want a `nanmean`).

Any better approach?

**Setup**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 2)), columns=['A', 'B'])

df[df>5] = np.nan  # EDIT: add nans
```

**My Attempt**

```
n_roll = 2

df_stacked = df.values
roll_avg = {}
for idx in range(n_roll, len(df_stacked)+1):
    roll_avg[idx-1] = np.nanmean(df_stacked[idx - n_roll:idx, :].flatten())

roll_avg = pd.Series(roll_avg)
roll_avg.index = df.index[n_roll-1:]
roll_avg = roll_avg.reindex(df.index)
```

**Desired Result**

```
roll_avg
Out[33]: 
0         NaN
1    5.000000
2    1.666667
3    0.333333
4    1.000000
5    3.000000
6    3.250000
7    3.250000
8    3.333333
9    4.000000
```

Thanks!

Comment: [using-rolling-on-multiple-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615849/pandas-using-rolling-on-multiple-columns/51616256#51616256) may be of use. You can either use `.shift`, or stack and then roll over a bigger window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one NumPy solution with sliding windows off `view_as_windows` -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

# Setup o/p array
out = np.full(len(df),np.nan)

# Get sliding windows of length n_roll along axis=0
w = view_as_windows(df.values,(n_roll,1))[...,0]

# Assign nan-ignored mean values computed along last 2 axes into o/p
out[n_roll-1:] = np.nanmean(w, (1,2))
```

Memory efficiency with `views` -

```
In [62]: np.shares_memory(df,w)
Out[62]: True
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Any way I can can avoid using skimage? does not seem to be included in standard anaconda distribution/my current environment

Comment: @FLab You can use the [`source code`](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/util/shape.py#L106).

Comment: @FLab Or use [`strided_axis0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413801/3293881) :  `np.nanmean(strided_axis0(df.values, n_roll),(1,2))`.

Comment: thanks it is working with strided_axis0. I just noticed that if all the values in the window are nan I have a RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice
  from code import InteractiveConsole  and this seems to affect time performance, so it is not as quick as the 'stack' solution I posted

Comment: @FLab Not sure how warnings can affect performance. How about turn off warnings at the top?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to get the same result in case of `nan`, you can use `column_stack` on all the `df.shift(i).values for i in range(n_roll)`, use `nanmean` on axis=1, and then you need to replace the first `n_roll-1` value with `nan` after:

```
roll_avg = pd.Series(np.nanmean(np.column_stack([df.shift(i).values for i in range(n_roll)]),1))
roll_avg[:n_roll-1] = np.nan
```

and with the second input with `nan`, you get as expected

```
0         NaN
1    5.000000
2    1.666667
3    0.333333
4    1.000000
5    3.000000
6    3.250000
7    3.250000
8    3.333333
9    4.000000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615849/pandas-using-rolling-on-multiple-columns/51616256#51616256) referenced in the comment, one can do:

```
wsize = n_roll
cols = df.shape[1]
out = group.stack(dropna=False).rolling(window=wsize * cols, min_periods=1).mean().reset_index(-1, drop=True).sort_index()
out.groupby(out.index).last()
out.iloc[:nroll-1] = np.nan
```

In my case it was important to specify `dropna=False` in `stack`, otherwise the length of the rolling window would not be correct.

But I am looking forward to other approaches as this does not feel very elegant/efficient.