# Pandas rolling apply using multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I am trying to use a `pandas.DataFrame.rolling.apply()` rolling function on multiple columns.
Python version is 3.7, pandas is 1.0.2.

```
import pandas as pd

#function to calculate
def masscenter(x):
    print(x); # for debug purposes
    return 0;

#simple DF creation routine
df = pd.DataFrame( [['02:59:47.000282', 87.60, 739],
                    ['03:00:01.042391', 87.51, 10],
                    ['03:00:01.630182', 87.51, 10],
                    ['03:00:01.635150', 88.00, 792],
                    ['03:00:01.914104', 88.00, 10]], 
                   columns=['stamp', 'price','nQty'])
df['stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['stamp'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f')
df.set_index('stamp', inplace=True, drop=True)
```

`'stamp'` is monotonic and unique, `'price'` is double and contains no NaNs, `'nQty'` is integer and also contains no NaNs.

So, I need to calculate rolling 'center of mass', i.e. `sum(price*nQty)/sum(nQty)`.

What I tried so far:

```
df.apply(masscenter, axis = 1)
```

`masscenter` is be called 5 times with a single row and the output will be like

```
price     87.6
nQty     739.0
Name: 1900-01-01 02:59:47.000282, dtype: float64
```

It is desired input to a `masscenter`, because I can easily access `price` and `nQty` using `x[0], x[1]`. However, I stuck with `rolling.apply()`
Reading the docs
[DataFrame.rolling()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and [rolling.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html)
I supposed that using `'axis'` in `rolling()` and `'raw'` in `apply` one achieves similiar behaviour. A naive approach

```
rol = df.rolling(window=2)
rol.apply(masscenter)
```

prints row by row (increasing number of rows up to window size)

```
stamp
1900-01-01 02:59:47.000282    87.60
1900-01-01 03:00:01.042391    87.51
dtype: float64
```

then

```
stamp
1900-01-01 02:59:47.000282    739.0
1900-01-01 03:00:01.042391     10.0
dtype: float64
```

So, columns is passed to `masscenter` separately (expected).

Sadly, in the docs there is barely any info about `'axis'`. However the next variant was, obviously

```
rol = df.rolling(window=2, axis = 1)
rol.apply(masscenter)
```

Never calls `masscenter` and raises `ValueError in rol.apply(..)`

```
> Length of passed values is 1, index implies 5
```

I admit that I'm not sure about `'axis'` parameter and how it works due to lack of documentation. It is the first part of the question:
**What is going on here? How to use 'axis' properly? What it is designed for?**

Of course, there were answers previously, namely:

[How-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe)
It works for the whole DataFrame, not Rolling.

[How-to-invoke-pandas-rolling-apply-with-parameters-from-multiple-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878917/how-to-invoke-pandas-rolling-apply-with-parameters-from-multiple-column)
The answer suggests to write my own roll function, but the culprit for me is the same as asked in  [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878917/how-to-invoke-pandas-rolling-apply-with-parameters-from-multiple-column#comment99035791_38879051): what if one needs to use offset window size (e.g. `'1T'`) for non-uniform timestamps?
I don't like the idea to reinvent the wheel from scratch. Also I'd like to use pandas for everything to prevent inconsistency between sets obtained from pandas and 'self-made roll'.
There is another answer to that question, suggessting to populate dataframe separately and calculate whatever I need, but it will not work: the size of stored data will be enormous.
The same idea presented here:
[Apply-rolling-function-on-pandas-dataframe-with-multiple-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59574934/apply-rolling-function-on-pandas-dataframe-with-multiple-arguments)

Another Q & A posted here
[Pandas-using-rolling-on-multiple-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615849/pandas-using-rolling-on-multiple-columns)
It is good and the closest to my problem, but again, there is no possibility to use offset window sizes (`window = '1T'`).

Some of the answers were asked before pandas 1.0 came out, and given that docs could be much better, I hope it is possible to roll over multiple columns simultaneously now.

The second part of the question is:
**Is there any possibility to roll over multiple columns simultaneously using pandas 1.0.x with offset window size?**

Comment: masscenter is just a function that maps every x into zero?

Comment: df2['stamp'] undefined though. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @HighGPA the 'masscenter' function was constructed this way to create a minimal, reproducible example. Have you declared ```columns=['stamp', 'price','nQty']```?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

How about this:

```py
import pandas as pd

def masscenter(ser: pd.Series, df: pd.DataFrame):
    df_roll = df.loc[ser.index]
    return your_actual_masscenter(df_roll)

masscenter_output = df['price'].rolling(window=3).apply(masscenter, args=(df,))
```

It uses the rolling logic to get subsets via an arbitrary column. The arbitrary column itself is not used, only the rolling index is used. This relies on the default of `raw=False` which provides the index values for those subsets. The applied function uses those index values to get multi-column slices from the original dataframe.

Comment: This is the answer at least for the second part. I knew that it should be possible. Such simple and pythonic solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a very expensive solution, though, for larger datasets.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your observation?

Comment: "then you use those index values to get multi-column slices from your original DataFrame" - do you mean `.iloc[i, c]` to reach into the dataframe from inside `masscenter`? i.e. `masscenter` doesn't have the arguments it needs directly?

Comment: Works for me though pandas' devs should really implement this somehow...

Comment: Could not more agree with @w00dy, should be made as an issue  : such a useful tool that would be

Comment: it is a nice solution, but then you have to hardcore df into the function masscenter; how do you solve that?

Comment: Could be a new question...

Comment: ...but look at the documentation for `apply` first.

Comment: Use a closure to put df in the lexical scope of masscenter.

Comment: @lele1c Maybe you can add a solution that does this?

Comment: The answer has been duly updated to provide `df` into the applied function as per the docs of [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html),

Answer (score 20):

You can use **rolling_apply** function from [numpy_ext](https://pypi.org/project/numpy-ext/) module:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy_ext import rolling_apply


def masscenter(price, nQty):
    return np.sum(price * nQty) / np.sum(nQty)


df = pd.DataFrame( [['02:59:47.000282', 87.60, 739],
                    ['03:00:01.042391', 87.51, 10],
                    ['03:00:01.630182', 87.51, 10],
                    ['03:00:01.635150', 88.00, 792],
                    ['03:00:01.914104', 88.00, 10]], 
                   columns=['stamp', 'price','nQty'])
df['stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['stamp'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f')
df.set_index('stamp', inplace=True, drop=True)

window = 2
df['y'] = rolling_apply(masscenter, window, df.price.values, df.nQty.values)
print(df)

                            price  nQty          y
stamp                                             
1900-01-01 02:59:47.000282  87.60   739        NaN
1900-01-01 03:00:01.042391  87.51    10  87.598798
1900-01-01 03:00:01.630182  87.51    10  87.510000
1900-01-01 03:00:01.635150  88.00   792  87.993890
1900-01-01 03:00:01.914104  88.00    10  88.000000
```

Comment: Thank you, but alas! It also accepts fixed window size - 2 (or whatever number) of *points*, but not *seconds* or another so-called *offsets*. However, you gave me an idea. I will try it and if it works will post soon.

Comment: If your data is not too sparse, you could use rolling_apply as suggested using a window large enough to encompass given time offset records, and incorporate a bounds check against the stamp inside the applied function. You might need to use large windows, but potentially rolling_apply's ability to execute parallel jobs might make up for that.

Answer (score 6):

With reference to the excellent answer from @saninstein.

Install numpy_ext from: https://pypi.org/project/numpy-ext/

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy_ext import rolling_apply as rolling_apply_ext

def box_sum(a,b):
    return np.sum(a) + np.sum(b)

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,2,3,4], "y": [1,2,3,4]})

window = 2
df["sum"] = rolling_apply_ext(box_sum, window , df.x.values, df.y.values)
```

Output:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
 x  y  sum
 1  1  NaN
 2  2  6.0
 3  3 10.0
 4  4 14.0
```

Notes

- The rolling function is timeseries friendly. It defaults to always looking backwards, so the 6 is the sum of present and past values in the array.
- In the sample above, imported `rolling_apply` as `rolling_apply_ext` so it cannot possibly interfere with any existing calls to Pandas `rolling_apply` (thanks to comment by @LudoSchmidt).

As a side note, I gave up trying to use Pandas. It's fundamentally broken: it handles single-column aggreagate and apply with little problems, but it's a overly complex rube-goldberg machine when trying to get it to work with more two columns or more.

Comment: personal expérience with your respond : I pip install and used "from numpy_ext import rolling_apply". But it destroyed my pandas in my script.

Comment: @LudoSchmidt Good point. Updated code above to import `rolling_apply` as `rolling_apply_ext`, so everything is backwards compatible with the existing `rolling_apply` calls in Pandas.

Comment: "I gave up trying to use Pandas. It's fundamentally broken" - this, unfortunately.

Comment: how would you do this on a GroupBy?

Answer (score 4):

For performing a rolling window operation with access to all columns of a dataframe, you can pass `mehtod='table'` to `rolling()`. Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'b': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]})

@jit
def f(w):
    # we have access to both columns of the dataframe here
    return np.max(w), np.min(w)

df.rolling(3, method='table').apply(f, raw=True, engine='numba')
```

It should be noted that `method='table'` requires numba engine (`pip install numba`). The `@jit` part in the example is not mandatory but helps with performance. The result of the above example code will be:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN |
| 5.0 | 1.0 |
| 7.0 | 2.0 |
| 9.0 | 3.0 |
| 11.0 | 4.0 |

Answer (score 1):

So I found no way to roll over two columns, however without inbuilt pandas functions.
The code is listed below.

```
# function to find an index corresponding
# to current value minus offset value
def prevInd(series, offset, date):
    offset = to_offset(offset)
    end_date = date - offset
    end = series.index.searchsorted(end_date, side="left")
    return end

# function to find an index corresponding
# to the first value greater than current
# it is useful when one has timeseries with non-unique
# but monotonically increasing values
def nextInd(series, date):
    end = series.index.searchsorted(date, side="right")
    return end

def twoColumnsRoll(dFrame, offset, usecols, fn, columnName = 'twoColRol'):
    # find all unique indices
    uniqueIndices = dFrame.index.unique()
    numOfPoints = len(uniqueIndices)
    # prepare an output array
    moving = np.zeros(numOfPoints)
    # nameholders
    price = dFrame[usecols[0]]
    qty   = dFrame[usecols[1]]

    # iterate over unique indices
    for ii in range(numOfPoints):
        # nameholder
        pp = uniqueIndices[ii]
        # right index - value greater than current
        rInd = afta.nextInd(dFrame,pp)
        # left index - the least value that 
        # is bigger or equal than (pp - offset)
        lInd = afta.prevInd(dFrame,offset,pp)
        # call the actual calcuating function over two arrays
        moving[ii] = fn(price[lInd:rInd], qty[lInd:rInd])
    # construct and return DataFrame
    return pd.DataFrame(data=moving,index=uniqueIndices,columns=[columnName])
```

This code works, but it is relatively slow and inefficient. I suppose one can use numpy.lib.stride_tricks from [How to invoke pandas.rolling.apply with parameters from multiple column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878917/how-to-invoke-pandas-rolling-apply-with-parameters-from-multiple-column) to speedup things.
However, go big or go home - I ended writing a function in C++ and a wrapper for it.

I'd like not to post it as answer, since it is a workaround and I have not answered neither part of my question, but it is too long for a commentary.

Answer (score 1):

```
(df['price'] * df['nQty']).rolling(2).sum() / df['nQty'].rolling(2).sum()

# output
    stamp
1900-01-01 02:59:47.000282          NaN
1900-01-01 03:00:01.042391    87.598798
1900-01-01 03:00:01.630182    87.510000
1900-01-01 03:00:01.635150    87.993890
1900-01-01 03:00:01.914104    88.000000
dtype: float64
```

You can use rolling sum for `price*nQty` and `nQty` part then calculating the mean. The same solution can be used with offset window size.

Comment: This works, but one needs to compute rolling more than once, so the solution is (very) slow for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
ggg = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], "b":[7,6,5,4,3,2,1]})

def my_rolling_apply2(df, fun, window):
    prepend = [None] * (window - 1)
    end = len(df) - window
    mid = map(lambda start: fun(df[start:start + window]), np.arange(0,end))
    last =  fun(df[end:])
    return [*prepend, *mid, last]

my_rolling_apply2(ggg, lambda df: (df["a"].max(), df["b"].min()), 3)
```

And result is:

```
[None, None, (3, 5), (4, 4), (5, 3), (6, 2), (7, 1)]
```