# Why does pandas rolling apply throw ValueError when used on axis=1?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

### **Overview**

I am getting a ValueError when trying to apply a simple function over a dataframe with `axis=1` (details below). It looks like it is trying to unpack the output into the columns of the dataframe instead of rows. The problem seems to be related to the `apply()` specifically, and only occurs when `axis=1` is used. Why is this error occurring?

### **Example**

Here is a simple example to reproduce the error (obviously in my use case the function I actually want to apply does not exist as a pandas built in):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data and dummy function
df = df = pd.DataFrame(2 * np.arange(10).reshape(2,5) - 1, columns=list('abcde'))

def my_min(s):
    """
    expects a series as input, outputs the min value
    """
    return s.min()

# when try to apply rolling across the rows it throws error
df.rolling(window=3, min_periods=3, axis=1).apply(my_min)
```

The relevant part of the traceback is:

[image]

### **Expected output**

It works when using the built in min, which is why I guess the problem is related to the apply function itself:

```
df.rolling(window=3, min_periods=2, axis=1).min()
```

Gives the expected output:

[image]

### **What I have tried**

1. Checking docs at [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html), there doesn't seem to be any useful hints. Just that the apply function should expect a series (when Raw=False, which is default behaviour) and return a scalar.
2. I also note that when I first transpose the dataframe and run on `axis=0`, it works fine. So an easy workaround is `df.T.rolling(window=3, min_periods=2, axis=0).apply(my_min).T`. But it does not answer my question as to why the behaviour is different when rolling across `axis=1`.
3. I have noted a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736556/pandas-rolling-apply-using-multiple-columns), but as far as I can tell it does not answer mine.

**Thanks!**

Comment: your expected output seems wrong - with `min_periods=3` the first two columns should have all NaNs - also your code doesn't error out for me

Comment: You are right - typo. I updated it. What version of pandas are you using? My pandas is 1.3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't produce an error with the latest pandas (1.4.4):

```
pd.__version__
1.4.4

df.rolling(window=3, min_periods=3, axis=1).apply(my_min)
    a   b    c     d     e
0 NaN NaN -1.0   1.0   3.0
1 NaN NaN  9.0  11.0  13.0
```

Versions older than 1.4.1 are impacted (issue [#45912](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/45912)). A workaround is to use `raw=True`:

```
df.rolling(window=3, min_periods=3, axis=1).apply(my_min, raw=True)
```