# Attempting to find location of values in a pandas Dataframe if certain conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, algorithmic-trading

I have this DataFrame.

```
                             High     Close    
Close Time                                                                                                                    
2022-10-23 21:41:59.999  19466.02  19461.29       
2022-10-23 21:42:59.999  19462.48  19457.83         
2022-10-23 21:43:59.999  19463.13  19460.09         
2022-10-23 21:44:59.999  19465.15  19463.76
```

I'm attempting to check if `Close` at a later date (up to 600 rows later but no more) goes above the close of an earlier date `& High` is lower than the High of the same earlier date then I want to get the location of both the earlier and later date and make new columns in the Dataframe with those locations.

Expected output:

```
                             High     Close         LC        HC         HH        LH
Close Time                                                                                                                    
2022-10-23 21:41:59.999  19466.02  19461.29   19461.29       NaN   19466.02       NaN
2022-10-23 21:42:59.999  19462.48  19457.83        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN
2022-10-23 21:43:59.999  19463.13  19460.09        NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN
2022-10-23 21:44:59.999  19465.15  19463.76        NaN  19463.76        NaN  19465.15
```

This is the code I have tried

```
    # Checking if conditions are met

    for i in range(len(df)):
        for a in range(i,600):
            if (df.iloc[i:, 1] < df.iloc[a, 1]) & (df.iloc[i:, 0] > df.iloc[a, 0]):

                # Creating new DataFrame columns

                df['LC'] = df.iloc[i, 1]
                df['HC'] = df.get_loc[i,1]
                df['HH'] = df.get_loc[a, 0]
                df['LH'] = df.get_loc[a, 0]

            else:
                continue
```

This line: `if (df.iloc[i:, 1] < df.iloc[a, 1]) & (df.iloc[i:, 0] > df.iloc[a, 0]):`
Is causing error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I believe I should be using `any()` instead of an if statement but I am unsure of how to apply it. I also think that there many be an issue with the way I am using the `df.get_loc[]` but I am unsure. I'm a pandas beginner so if it is obvious I apologize

Here is an image to help visualise what I am attempting to do using a candlestick chart
[image]

what I want to do is check if HC is higher than LC *and* LH is lower than HH then add that data to new columns in the DataFrame

Here is an additional way I tried to achieve the desired output

```
idx_close, idx_high = map(df.columns.get_loc, ["Close", "High"])

    # Check Conditions
    for i in range(len(df)):
        bool_l = [((df.iloc[i, idx_close] < df.iloc[a, idx_close]) &
                    (df.iloc[i, idx_high] > df.iloc[a, idx_high])
                     ).any() for a in range(i, 600)]

        # Creating new DataFrame columns
        df.loc[i, 'LC'] = df.iloc[i,1]
        df.loc[bool_l, 'HC'] = df.iloc[bool_l, 1]

        # Creating new DataFrame columns
        df.loc[i, 'HH'] = df.iloc[i, 0]
        df.loc[bool_l, 'LH'] = df.iloc[bool_l, 0]
```

And I get an error `IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 600 instead of 2867`
On the line `df.loc[bool_l, 'HC'] = df.iloc[bool_l, 1]`
I assume the error comes from the `range(i,600)` but I don't know how to get around it

Comment: In your question, it is unclear what you want. please clarify the sentance: "I'm attempting to check if `Close` at a later date (up to 600 rows later but no more) goes above the close of an earlier date & `High` is lower than the High of the same earlier date then I want to get the location of both the earlier and later date and make new columns in the `Dataframe` with those locations." In any case, I suspect you will want to look into `.rolling()` [docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and `.shift()` methods of dataframes.

Comment: @LarryBird What I want to do is check if HC is higher than LC and LH is lower than HH then add that data to new columns in the DataFrame. See the circled sections on the candlestick chart image to understand what HC, LC, LH and HH are. notice in this candlestick chart those conditions I want the code to detect are present however the candlesticks either side of the circled ones the conditions arent present and I want the code to ignore those.

Comment: @LarryBird The '600 rows' I talk about is 600 candles, a candle is made up of data from 1 row of the dataframe. I want to be able to check the conditions mentioned in the comment above up to 600 candles after the current candle. Potentially an easier way to do it would be to look back at the 600 candles before the current candle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Jimpsoni, the question is a little unclear in defining what you mean by `LC`, `HC`, `HH` and `HL`. I will use the below definitions to answer your question:

- `C_t` is the close price on a given day, `t`
- `H_t` is the high price on a given dat, `t`

Then if I understand correctly, you want to check the following two conditions:

1. **close condition:** is there a future close price in the next 600 days which is higher than the the current close price?
2. **high condition:** is there a future high price in the next 600 days which is lower than the high price from today?

And then for each day `t`, you want to find the **first day** in the future where both the conditions above are **satisfied simultaneously**.

With this understanding, I sketch a solution below.

### Part 1: Setting up sample data (do this in your question next time)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2022)

# make example data
close = np.sin(range(610)) + 10
high = close + np.random.rand(*close.shape)
close[2] += 100  # to ensure the close condition cannot be met
dates = pd.date_range(end='2022-06-30', periods=len(close))

# insert into pd.dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates, data=np.array([close, high]).T, columns=['close', 
'high'])
```

The sample dataframe looks like below:

[image]

### Part 2: Understand how to use rolling functions

Since at each point in time you want to subset your dataframe to a particular view in a rolling manner (always look 600 forward), it makes sense to use the built in `.rolling` method of pandas dataframes here. The `.rolling()` method is similar to a groupby in the sense that it allows you to iterate over different subsets of the dataframe, without explicitly writing the loop. `rolling` by default looks backwards, so we need to import a forward looking indexer to achieve the forward window. Note that you can also achieve the same forward window with some shifting, but it is less intuitive. The below chunk demonstrates how both methods give you the same result:

```
# create the rolling window object
# the simplest solution is to use the fixed size forward window as below
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=600)
method_1 = df.rolling(indexer, min_periods=600).sum()

# can also achieve the same thing by doing the rolling computation and then shifting backward
method_2 = df.rolling(600, min_periods=600).sum().shift(-599)

# confirm they are the same
(method_1.dropna() == method_2.dropna()).mean().mean() # returns 1.0
```

### Part 3: Write the logic that will be applied to each rolling view

Once we have the rolling frame, we can simply apply a function that will be applied to each rolling view of the dataframe. Here is the function, below will be some comments:

```
def check_conditions(ser, df_full):
    
    df_chunk = df_full.loc[ser.index, :]
    
    today_close, today_high = df_chunk.iloc[0,:2]
    future_close_series, future_high_series = df_chunk.iloc[1:, 0], df_chunk.iloc[1:, 1]
    
    close_condition = today_close < future_close_series
    high_condition = today_high > future_high_series
    both_condition = close_condition & high_condition
    
    if both_condition.sum() == 0:
        return 1
    
    first_date_satisfied = future_close_series.index[np.where(both_condition)][0]
    future_vals = df_chunk.loc[first_date_satisfied, ['close','high']].values
    df_full.loc[ser.index[0], ['Future_Close', 'Future_High', 'Future_Date']] = np.append(future_vals, first_date_satisfied)
    
    return 1
```

**Some comments:** First, notice that the function takes two arguments, the first is a series, and the second is the full dataframe. Unfortunately, the `.rolling()` only acts on a single column / row at a time. This is in contrast to `.groupby()` which allows access to the full dataframe produced by each group. To get around this, I use a pattern proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60918101/19020980), where we use the index of the series (the series is the rolling view on a single column of the dataframe) to subset the full dataframe appropriately. Then check the conditions on appropriately subset dataframe with all columns available, and modify that dataframe when the conditions match. This may not be particularly memory efficient as pointed out in the comments to that answer linked above.

### Final part: run the function

Here we set up the `df_full` dataframe, and then use rolling and apply the function to generate the output:

```
df_out = df.copy()
df_out[['Future_Close','Future_High','Future_Date']] = np.nan
_ = df.rolling(indexer, min_periods=600).apply(lambda x: check_conditions(x, df_out))

df_out
```

In `df_out`, the extra column will be `NaN` if no day in the next 600 days meet the criteria. If a day does meet the criteria, the close and high price on that day, as well as the date, are attached.
Output looks like:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular for loop to iterate over dataframe is slow, instead you should use pandas built-in methods for dataframe because they are much faster.

Series has a built-in method **diff()** that iterates over that series and compares every value to previous one. So you could get 2 new serieses that each has information whether the previous close was less than todays

```
# You need numpy for this, if already imported, ignore this line
import numpy as np

# Make series for close and high
close = df["Close"].diff()
high = df["High"].diff()
```

I think you want to have lower "high" value and higher "close" value but with this logic it doesn't generate desired output.

```
# Then create new columns
df['LC'] = np.where((close > 0) & (high < 0), np.NaN, df["Close"])
df['HC'] = np.where((close > 0) & (high < 0), np.NaN, df["High"])
df['HH'] = np.where((close > 0) & (high < 0), np.NaN, df["Close"])
df['LH'] = np.where((close > 0) & (high < 0), np.NaN, df["High"])
```

if you provide more infomation about what LC, HC, HH, LH are supposed to be, or provide more examples, I can help you get correct results.

Comment: In your code instead of (close > 0) & (high < 0) what I need to check is if (close > any of the next 600 close values. (say close[550] is greater that is the condition met)) & (high < high[550] (the same index as the higher close) I have updated the visual candlestick chart to hopefully make things clearer –