# Pandas find first row matching condition (or last if not found) in a forward-rolling window

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with two columns `j` and `k`. I'd like to do a 3-element forward rolling calculation like this:

1. Find the first element (in order) in `k` that's smaller than `j` if it exists
2. Otherwise - if all elements in `k` are greater than `j` - use the last (in order) from `k`

The result would go into column `l`.

Example:

```
numpy.random.seed(1)

df = pandas.DataFrame(dict(
  j=numpy.random.randint(10, 99, 12),
  k=numpy.random.randint(10, 99, 12),
))

# Expected result
df['l'] = [16, 30, 60, 94, 28, 38, 21, 38, 24, 78, numpy.nan, numpy.nan]

print(df)
```

Dataframe with `j` and `k` which are the input columns and manually populated `l` with the expected result (with some comments):

```
     j   k     l
0   47  16  16.0 # Case 1, 47 > 16, so put 16
1   22  35  30.0 # Case 2, 22 < [35, 60, 30], so put 30
2   82  60  60.0 # Case 1, 82 > 60, so put 60
3   19  30  94.0 # Case 2, 19 < [30, 28, 94], so put 94
4   85  28  28.0 # Case 1, 85 > 28, so put 28
5   15  94  38.0 # Case 1, 15 < [94, 21, 38], so put 38
6   89  21  21.0 # Case 1, 89 > 21, so put 21
7   74  38  38.0 # Case 1, 74 < 38, so put 38
8   26  39  24.0 # Case 1, 26 < 39, but 26 > 24, so put 24
9   11  24  78.0 # Case 2, 11 < [24, 60, 78], so put 78
10  86  60   NaN # If easier, l = 60 is fine
11  81  78   NaN # If easier, l = 78 is fine
```

Any idea how I can do this using pandas without manually iterating (i.e. benefiting from vectorization)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `shift` to align all values of the rolling windows on k with the value of j. Then keep only the values `where` they are less than the column j. Use `bfill` along the columns to get the first non null value found in the row back to the first column, that you can select with `iloc[:, 0]` and `fillna` the rows with no value using the last value in the rolling window of k.

```
roll_win = 3
df['l_calc'] = (
    pd.concat([df['k'].shift(-i) for i in range(roll_win)], axis=1)
      .where(lambda x: x.lt(df['j'], axis=0))
      .bfill(axis=1)
      .iloc[:,0]
      .fillna(df['k'].shift(-roll_win+1))
)
print(df)
#      j   k     l  l_calc
# 0   47  16  16.0    16.0
# 1   22  35  30.0    30.0
# 2   82  60  60.0    60.0
# 3   19  30  94.0    94.0
# 4   85  28  28.0    28.0
# 5   15  94  38.0    38.0
# 6   89  21  21.0    21.0
# 7   74  38  38.0    38.0
# 8   26  39  24.0    24.0
# 9   11  24  78.0    78.0
# 10  86  60   NaN    60.0
# 11  81  78   NaN    78.0
```

Note: technically, because of the `fillna` at the end, you don't need to care about the comparison with this column and in the concat, do only the `range(win_roll-1)`, you would save some time if your data is large

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! Curious, is a solution possible with forward-looking rolling windows?

Comment: @levantpied so forward rolling is usually done by reversing the order of the dataframe and then do a regular backward rolling and then reverse the order. That said, rolling using several columns in the rolling function is not that easy, [see this QA for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736556/pandas-rolling-apply-using-multiple-columns) except if new version of pandas have this implemented.

Comment: @levantpied If your concern is about bigger window, hence a lot of shift, you can have a look at a [numpy version of rolling windows](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view), I never used it maybe

Comment: Great, thanks Ben.T! I'll check these out.