# OSError - could not get source code, during Pandas rolling apply an iterative function

Tags: python, dataframe, rolling-computation, oserror, iterated-function

I am encountering an issue related to the Pandas `rolling` function in Python.

Specifically, I am implementing a rolling apply with a custom function, and I'm facing an `OSError: could not get source code` error.

This is my DataFrame

| gvkey | PERMNO | date | Xt | Ve | sigma_E | rf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1004 | 54594 | 2011-09-30 | 178.9760 | 674484.87 | 0.000000 | 0.000003 |
| 1004 | 54594 | 2011-10-03 | 178.9760 | 613793.373 | 30345.750000 | 0.000003 |

This is the function I defined with an iterator function nested inside it

```
def cal_sigma_A(x):
    ite_sig = x.sigma_E.iloc[-1]
    ite_Va = x.Ve

    def iterative_sigma(x, sig = ite_sig, Va = ite_Va):
    
        d1 = (np.log(Va/x.Xt) + (x.rf + 0.5*(sig**2)))/sig
        d2 = d1 - sig
        d1 = norm.cdf(d1)
        d2 = norm.cdf(d2)
        new_Va = (x.Ve + x.Xt*np.exp(-x.rf)*d2)/d1
        new_sigma = np.std(new_Va)
        if new_sigma - sig < 10*(-4):
            return new_sigma
        else:
            return iterative_sigma(x,new_sigma,new_Va)
    return iterative_sigma(x,ite_sig,ite_Va)
```

```
merged.set_index('date').groupby(['gvkey','PERMNO'],group_keys=False).rolling('365D').apply(lambda x:cal_sigma_A(x))
```

And this is the error:

```
Unexpected exception formatting exception. Falling back to standard exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3526, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "C:\Users\28137\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11788\4089525893.py", line 1, in <module>
    merged.groupby(['gvkey','PERMNO'],group_keys=False).rolling('365D').apply(lambda x:cal_sigma_A(x))
  File "d:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 1913, in apply
    return super().apply(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 1390, in apply
    return self._apply(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 709, in _apply
    result = super()._apply(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 615, in _apply
    return self._apply_blockwise(homogeneous_func, name, numeric_only)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 490, in _apply_blockwise
    res = homogeneous_func(arr)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 610, in homogeneous_func
    result = calc(values)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\rolling.py", line 607, in calc
    return func(x, start, end, min_periods, *numba_args)
...
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\anaconda\Lib\inspect.py", line 1081, in findsource
    raise OSError('could not get source code')
OSError: could not get source code
```

Additionaly, if I only want to execute this function at the end of each month, what's the best way to do it?

I'm a newbie, so I have no idea how to debug.

Comment: You get an error because `x` is not each row by each column, try just printing x in your lambda func instead to see that

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, I just learned the correct usage of rolling, it only applies the function to a column and not the whole dataframe? May I ask what is the correct way to do this if I wish to apply a rolling apply function to multiple columns? I'd like to apply my function to the past year's data at the end of each month, what is the recommended method? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you reduce your problem, it becomes how to apply rolling on multiple columns. There are a few related problems on SO, one of them is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60743386/6385519).

You can use [rolling_apply](https://3jane.github.io/numpy_ext/#numpy_ext.rolling_apply) from `numpy_ext` package (you'll have to install that). Tweaking your original code a little, the below code works (though you have to be careful with recursion limit, if your function keeps on calling itself without returning).

```
# !pip install numpy_ext
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm
from numpy_ext import rolling_apply as rolling_apply_ext
import numpy as np
def func1(ite_Va, sigma_E, Xt, rf, Ve):
  ite_sig = sigma_E.iloc[-1]
  def iterative_sigma(xt, rf, Ve, sig = ite_sig, Va = ite_Va):
    
        d1 = (np.log(Va/xt) + (rf + 0.5*(sig**2)))/sig
        d2 = d1 - sig
        d1 = norm.cdf(d1)
        d2 = norm.cdf(d2)
        new_Va = (Ve + Xt*np.exp(-rf)*d2)/d1
        new_sigma = np.std(new_Va)
        # if new_sigma - sig < 10*(-4):
        return new_sigma
        # else:
        #     return iterative_sigma(xt,rf,Ve,new_sigma,new_Va)
  return iterative_sigma(Xt,rf,Ve,ite_sig,ite_Va)

window = 2
rolling_apply_ext(func1, window, df['Ve'], df['sigma_E'], df['Xt'], df['rf'], df['Ve'])
```